# Could not find Corda FAQ page using the published URL

Tags: corda

The "Frequently Asked Questions" document on Corda at link
"https://docs.corda.net/faq.html" says -

> > **A list of frequently asked questions can be found here: https://discourse.corda.net/c/faq.**

However on clicking the link - "https://discourse.corda.net/c/faq", the page says -

> > **"This site can’t be reached"**

Is the FAQ document available?

If yes, please share the link to that document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discourse is no longer in use - I guess you could say that the FAQ are now somewhat here on StackOverflow :)

On a serious note, a lot of the old FAQ from discourse has now been integrated into the docs themselves.